# The Hashable now want to use protocol instead of hashValue but I can't figure it out

Tags: swift4.2, hashable, swift5

I use to have the following code that worked in Swift 4.2 but is now deprecated in Swift 5:

```
struct xxx: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {return uniqueIdentifier}
```

When I try to use the new `hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)` I'm not sure what to do. My uniqueIdentifier starts at 0 and keeps incrementing so it's always unique, no need for anything fancy. But it seams to me that I'm now required to have the following code:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(uniqueIdentifier)
    }
```

Is this true? I don't see why I need to combined my uniqueIdentifier with some seed. Is there a way I can overcome this or I'm I stuck using `hasher.combine(uniqueIdentifier)`?